# Mathematica isnt accepting my equation

Tags: plotting, graphics

```
Plot[{[-1.51] + [42.5]*exp [[-3.82]*x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

is my equation but Mathematica isn't giving me any output...

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to plot your equation. The extra brackets in place of parentheses aren't needed.

```
Plot[{-1.51 + 42.5 Exp[-3.82 x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

There's a useful guide at [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/41569) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

WL commands are capitalized.  Brackets cannot be used as parentheses.

```
Plot[{-1.51 + 42.5*Exp[-3.82*x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```